# Where can I find project.properties in my project?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use proguard but it keeps telling me to look for a project.properties folder and post this code

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

the thing is I can't locate it. Where can I find it?

Comment: You should be using Android Studio. This is already taken care of for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio then you will not have a project.properties file as it uses the gradle build system.

You can add ProGuard into your gradle build as follows:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```

These lines should be automatically generated when you create a new Android Studio project, although minifyEnabled is set to false.

Comment: Is this all there is to it?

Comment: Yes, you can read more about including ProGuard with the Gradle plugin on the Android tools site. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard